# Excel 2013: this command is not available in a shared workbook (workbook not shared)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

A staff member is using Excel 2013, and receives the error: "this command is not available in a shared workbook" when trying to copy an existing sheet as a new sheet.

The Workbook is not shared.

I don't receive the same error if I open the Workbook, and copy and paste the same sheet.

Help appreciated.

Regards,

Steve.

Answer (score 2):

In Review > Track Changes > Highlight Changes > un-ticked "Track changes while editing. This also shares your workbook."

Problem resolved.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I was able to overcome this problem was to copy my worksheet from one workbook to a brand new one, then "Save As" to overwrite the old one after closing it.